# Удаление переносов строк в Memo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

****Загружаю в Memo1 список строк из текстового файла.****

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ 'stroki.txt');
```

Длина каждой строки **до 2000 символом**. Почему memo режет каждую строку и делает переходы, переносы части строки. Как этого избежать именно что бы каждая стока загрузилась в Memo без переноса. То есть загрузили **10 строк и в memo1 должно быть 10 строк.**

**Мои попытки:**

```
1. Изменить свойство WordWrap на False.
2. Memo1.Text:=StringReplace(Memo1.Text,#10#13,' ',[rfreplaceall])
3. Изменяла свойства ScrollBars.
```

Ничего с этого не помогло. Или это невозможно сделать ?

Comment: А зачем вам Memo?

Comment: @MBo, Просто интересно было про Memo. Я знаю что по моему в ListBox можно было сделать проще. Или какие варианты лучше ? Посоветуйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memo - визуальный контрол для удобного просмотра. Такие длинные строчки просматривать в любом случае неудобно, так что смысла в применении Memo для визуализации нет.

Использование визуального контрола как хранилища кучи информации- тоже порочная идея.

(Ограничение длины строк заложено и в самих виндах в недрах Edit Control, коим является Memo и внутри VCL -  например, `TMemoStrings.Get`)

---

А для хранения (больших) списков и работы с ними есть `TStringList`, где особых ограничений нет.

Нужно что-то показать - отберите минимально необходимую часть информации и показывайте хоть в Memo.

Comment: Сделала чрез TStringList и кстати тут таких неудобств нет. Спасибо за совет.